# The "R" Class are not recoginzed

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My layouts and views' ids, eclipse can not recognize them and underscore them with red line.
I built all the projects and cleaned them as well, but the problem still exists. Please provide any suggestions.

***UPDATE:***

The updated problem is, the `R` class is highlighted with red

JavaCode:

```
setContentView(R.layout.mplmenu_activity);

    mMainMenuListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView_Menu);
    String [] items = {   
 getResources().getString(R.string.menuItem_AddNewLocation),

 getResources().getString(R.string.menuItem_MySavedLocation),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.menuItem_GPSReadings),

 getResources().getString(R.string.menuItem_OpenCameraSurface)
                      };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapt =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  
R.layout.mainMenuItems, items);
```

mplmenu_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="match_parent">

      <LinearLayout 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:background="@color/mplMenuActivityBackGroundColor" >              
          <RelativeLayout 
              android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal">
              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="@string/menu"
                  android:textSize="@dimen/mainMenuTextSize"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                  android:shadowDx="0"
                  android:shadowDy="0"
                  android:shadowRadius="10"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"
                  android:textColor="@color/mainMenuTextColor">
              </TextView>    
          </RelativeLayout>

          <RelativeLayout
              android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_gravity="center">
              <ListView
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/ListView_Menu"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:divider="@drawable/dividerline"
                  android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
              </ListView>
          </RelativeLayout>    
      </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the generated `R.java` file actually exists. You may have errors in some of your XML resource files that prevent the Android build tool `aapt` from generating the `R.java` file. In my experience, that is typically why resource IDs are not found.

To fix this, you will have to fix the XML errors.

Comment: i fixed the xml's errors but the problem still persist

Comment: Does the R.java file exist? You may have to Clean your project. If it does not exist, then you have probably not found all the XML problems.

Comment: "R.Layout" is recognized but any layout's id is not

Comment: Make sure your layout's ID is the name of the layout XML file, without the ".xml" extension. For example, if the layout file is named `foo.xml`, its ID is `R.layout.foo`. If this does not solve your problem, then please provide your layout XML, and also the code that is causing the errors to be displayed.

Comment: `mplmenu_activity.xml` is missing the `</FrameLayout>` end tag at the very end. Is the actual file missing the end tag? If this is not the real problem, then you need to fix the XML errors being reported by eclipse (I assume you are using eclipse?). The eclipse Problems view (Window|Show View|Other...|General|Problems) will display all the errors.

Comment: yes i am using eclipse. my Framlayout is complete with all the closing tags included in the actual xml file

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like `import your_package_name.R` in your `Activity` class, remove it, and clean the project, then build it again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are identifying them in your xml with the +id and not just id.

Like this:
android:id="+id/btn1"

not this:
android:id="id/btn1"

Comment: Is it just the listview that is getting an error.  Might try and rename it in the xml and see if the new name still errors out.